# How to detect page have refreshed with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, web

Like title, how can i detect my webpage have [refreshed](/questions/tagged/refreshed)?

Comment: Use localstorage to set a specific value and have a check if that has not been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$('body').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function() {
     //Content refreshed.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('body').bind('beforeunload',function(){
   //do something
});
```

Comment: but if i want to do something after page refresh?

Comment: You can try this:
$('body').unload(function() {
  //do something
});

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with `localStorage`:

```
 $(function(){
   var ls = window.localStorage;
   if(ls.getItem['somevar']){
      // if found that means page
      // has been reloaded
      console.log('reloaded');
   } else {
      // when page is ready first time 
      // the value will be set to see if
      // user reloads the page again.
      ls.setItem['somevar'] = 1;
   }
 });
```